# DbContext.Query is not accepting generic type T, How to make a generic DbContext query in dot net core api?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I want make generic class to make query in sql database. My class is like that

```
public class GenericQuery<T>{
   private SomeContext context;
   GenericQuery(SomeContext _context){
      this.context = _context;
   }
   public T GetItemById(int id){
        Task<T> result = Task.Run(() => GetItemByIdAsync(id));
        result.Wait();
        return result.Result;
   }
   private T GetItemByIdAsync(int id){
       var typeName = x // x will extracted from type T using reflection.
       var procName = $"Get{x}"
       T result = this.context.Query<T>().FromSql("{0}, {1}",procName, id).FirstOrDefault();
       return result;
   }
}
```

But here in method `GetItemByIdAsync`, `this.context.Query<T>().FromSql(---)` is giving compilation Error as following -

```
**Error CS0452  The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TQuery' in the generic type or method 'methodName'**
```

how solve that?

Comment: "I want make generic class to make query in sql database" - **don't do this** - you're just recreating the repository anti-pattern which is not needed in Entity Framework.

Comment: Any better solution then? Because for this reason i have to keep repeating same code again and again for different model just changing the model only.

Comment: Please see my posted answer.

Comment: If you have any questions about my answer please post them as comment replies to my answer, not your question.

Comment: Sorry, the answer was collapsed. Didn't notice then.

Answer (score 3):

- If you're using Entity Framework (including Entity Framework Core) then it is an **anti-pattern** to define a "Repository" or "Generic Repository" type in your project.

  - This also applies to most other ORMs like NHibernate and even the older Linq-to-Sql system: the ORM provides the Repository for you already.
  - Specifically, your `DbContext` subclass is the Unit-of-Work object.
  - ...and the Entity Framework-owned `DbSet<T>` class is the actual Generic Repository type.
- Looking at your question, it's clear you just want to reduce repetitiveness in your codebase (DRY is important, after all) - but be careful about being too aggressive in implementing DRY because you may have different queries that *look* the same or similar but the differences might matter - so think carefully about what you're eliminating and that you won't be creating extra work for yourself or others in future.
- In my experience and in my professional opinion: the "best" way to centrally define common queries is by defining Extension Methods for your `DbContext` and/or `DbSet<T>` types that build (but do not materialize!) an `IQueryable<T>`.

  - Define generic extension-methods on `DbSet<T>` constrained with an interface if they apply to different entity types.
  - Define non-generic extension-methods on `DbSet<EntityTypeName>` if they're specific to a single entity type.
  - Define non-generic extension-methods on `DbContext` if they're queries for multiple entity types (e.g. a `JOIN` query).

    - These still could be constrained generic extension-methods too, but it's non-trivial to get a `DbSet<T>` object reference for any `T`.
- Another advantage of only defining methods that return `IQueryable<T>` is that you can **compose** them - which is a huge benefit if you have (for example) a complicated `.Where()` condition that you want to re-use in another query without repeating yourself.

Here's an example of a set of constrained generic extension-methods that return `IQueryable<T>`:

```
interface IHasId
{
    Int32 Id { get; }
}

interface IHasName
{
    String Name { get; }
}

public static class QueryExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> QueryById( this DbSet<T> dbSet, Int32 entityId )
        where T : IHasId
    {
        return dbSet.Where( e => e.Id == entityId  );
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> QueryByName( this DbSet<T> dbSet, String name )
        where T : IHasName
    {
        return dbSet.Where( e => e.Name == name );
    }
}

// You need to add the interfaces to your entity types, use partial classes for this if your entity types are auto-generated:

public partial class Person : IHasId, IHasName
{
}
```

Used like so:

```
MyDbContext db = ...

Person p = await db.People.QueryById( entityId: 123 ).SingleOrDefaultAsync();

List<Person> people = await db.People.QueryByName( name: "John Smith" ).ToListAsync();
```

---

And if you want to add materialized queries, then that's okay too (but you won't be able to compose them - which is why it's best to stick to only adding extensions that return `IQueryable<T>`:

```
public static class QueryExtensions
{
    public static Task<T> GetSingleAsync( this DbSet<T> dbSet, Int32 entityId )
        where T : IHasId
    {
        return dbSet.SingleOrDefaultAsync( e => e.Id == entityId );
    }

     public static Task<List<T>> GetAllByNameAsync( this DbSet<T> dbSet, String name )
        where T : IHasName
    {
        return dbSet.Where( e => e.Name == name ).ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Used like so:

```
MyDbContext db = ...

Person p = await db.People.GetSingleAsync( entityId: 123 );

List<Person> people = await db.People.GetAllByNameAsync( name: "John Smith" );
```

Comment: I am actually using store procedure as i mentioned here in ```this.context.Query<T>().FromSql("{0}, {1}",procName, id).FirstOrDefault();``` to run query in sql server. Here procName defines the StoreProcedure Name. Can you tell me the how can i handle that for query in database using store procedure.

Comment: @Shakibuz_Zaman Entity Framework can generate methods for stored-procedures by itself without you needing to add them yourself. Is there a reason you're not using EF's generated stored-procedure wrapper methods?

Comment: I thought generating queries for entity framwork core might be costly. If i generate the queries my own, it might be faster as the api don't need to generate the queries any more.

Comment: You shouldn't use Stored Procedures for read-only queries, that's what Table-Valued-Functions and Views as for (they can also be inlined by SQL Server). Only use stored-procedures for operations that mutate data. Also, what do you mean by "costly" (in terms of initialization cost? runtime performance? design-time cost?). I stress that EF  has a great reputation for generating optimal SQL for queries expressed using Linq-to-Entities, and as I said earlier: the ability to recompose `IQueryable<T>` is a tremendous advantage.

Comment: In my own projects - the only times I've needed to use a stored-procedure or write a query using  TVF is when I'm writing reports queries that use features of T-SQL that *cannot* be expressed at all when using Linq (e.g. recursive CTE queries, window functions or multi-result queries) or when using Linq would be too tedious (e.g. selecting a subset of columns without using anonymous types).

Comment: Can you look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739230/entity-framework-vs-stored-procedures-performance-measure)? EF is kind of almost 7 times slower than Store procedure. Actually first i was also interested to work with EF but than my brother told about the performance of EF and asked to continue with store procedure.

Comment: @Shakibuz_Zaman EF itself doesn't have any significant performance issues besides its initialization time (which is a one-time cost when your program starts). That question you linked to is from 2012 - and EF has changed a lot since then (as we're up to EF6 and EF Core 3 now) so much of the early criticism of EF really doesn't apply today. I also feel most of the answers advocating the use of stored-procedures that don't mention TVFs were probably sound at the time, but TVFs are amazing and EF supports using them directly.

Comment: Ok, Thank you @Dai for these informations. I will try to convince my co-workers to work with EF. 
But still i have curiosity of know the solution of my posted question. May be we were a bit out of context for a moment thought i am grateful to you for these informations. Is there any solution of my question?

Comment: @Shakibuz_Zaman "Is there any solution of my question?" - to what extent does my posted answer not answer your question? What gaps are left?

Comment: I am talking about the store procedure solution actually. You explained the EF implementation in your answer, if i am not wrong.