# Entity Framework performance is very slow

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to retrieve a data from the database using EF `Database.SqlQuery`. The below code is taking almost 15 seconds to execute to get output.

```
await _context.Database.SqlQuery<sp_dataexec>("exec sp_dataexec").ToListAsync()
```

If I try to execute `sp_dataexec` stored procedure in SQL Server it takes only 4 seconds to execute. This stored procedure `sp_dataexec` which contains only select statement and it has 85k records. Please let me know is there any alternative way to retrieve a data faster.

Comment: How much time do you expect it to take to read 85k rows, parse them and generate 85k objects in memory?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I'm expecting only 5 seconds.

Comment: Do you understand that SSMS does not parse the rows nor it generates objects in-memory, since it doesn't care about the types? You expect your computer to be able to do that 1 second, which isn't really logical. Perhaps you should consider reducing the data selected, or do whatever processing is needed in SQL Server rather than in memory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework Vs Stored Procedures - Performance Measure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739230/entity-framework-vs-stored-procedures-performance-measure)

Comment: @IndritKello do you have any sample code ?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: .AsNoTracking() !

Comment: @WiktorZychla How to use in EF sqlquery ?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - unclear how you imagine SSMS displays the results in the results grid without processing the rows. Certainly I would expect to be able to get 85K results from the DB and put them into a List of strongly typed objects with dapper in time faster than SSMS displays the results.

Comment: @MartinSmith AFAIK, SSMS doesn't need to worry about parsing different types, generating objects relationships, generating entity tracking state and whatever else plumbing EF does internally (Dapper isn't part of the question so I don't find that relevant here).

Comment: I was responding to your comment - that just indicates that it would be crazy to expect 85K objects to be generated in memory from a database resultset within a reasonable time frame.

Comment: Read [this](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: @Gowtham, Can you put up the entity definition you have for this sp_dataexec entity along with the stored procedure code as well? A lot hinges on what this data actually looks like, as well as the environment you are running. Is the DB on same server or a remote server from the app server running the application?

Answer (score 2):

EF parsing takes *some* time, but 11 seconds for 85,000 rows seems a bit much.  Make sure the DbContext isn't being reused and has a full ChangeTracker.

For comparision I scaffolded AdventureWorks2017 and loaded Sales.SalesOrderHeader:

```
public partial class SalesOrderHeader
{
    public int SalesOrderId { get; set; }
    public byte RevisionNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ShipDate { get; set; }
    public byte Status { get; set; }
    public bool? OnlineOrderFlag { get; set; }
    public string SalesOrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string PurchaseOrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int? SalesPersonId { get; set; }
    public int? TerritoryId { get; set; }
    public int BillToAddressId { get; set; }
    public int ShipToAddressId { get; set; }
    public int ShipMethodId { get; set; }
    public int? CreditCardId { get; set; }
    public string CreditCardApprovalCode { get; set; }
    public int? CurrencyRateId { get; set; }
    public decimal SubTotal { get; set; }
    public decimal TaxAmt { get; set; }
    public decimal Freight { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalDue { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public Guid Rowguid { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

And after warmup it was consistently around 100,000 rows/sec loading into the DbContext *including* query execution time.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    using (var db = new Adventureworks2017Context())
    {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        var orders = db.SalesOrderHeaders.ToList();
            
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Loaded {orders.Count()} rows in {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms, for {orders.Count() / (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0):F2}rows/sec");
    }
}
```

outputs

```
Loaded 31465 rows in 1206ms, for 26090.38rows/sec
Loaded 31465 rows in 273ms, for 115256.41rows/sec
Loaded 31465 rows in 281ms, for 111975.09rows/sec
Loaded 31465 rows in 244ms, for 128954.92rows/sec
Loaded 31465 rows in 228ms, for 138004.39rows/sec
Loaded 31465 rows in 260ms, for 121019.23rows/sec
Loaded 31465 rows in 251ms, for 125358.57rows/sec
Loaded 31465 rows in 224ms, for 140468.75rows/sec
Loaded 31465 rows in 261ms, for 120555.56rows/sec
Loaded 31465 rows in 223ms, for 141098.65rows/sec
```

Adding rows to the table didn't really change things:

```
Loaded 100000 rows in 1669ms, for 59916.12rows/sec
Loaded 100000 rows in 849ms, for 117785.63rows/sec
Loaded 100000 rows in 850ms, for 117647.06rows/sec
Loaded 100000 rows in 875ms, for 114285.71rows/sec
Loaded 100000 rows in 885ms, for 112994.35rows/sec
Loaded 100000 rows in 831ms, for 120336.94rows/sec
Loaded 100000 rows in 871ms, for 114810.56rows/sec
Loaded 100000 rows in 879ms, for 113765.64rows/sec
Loaded 100000 rows in 875ms, for 114285.71rows/sec
Loaded 100000 rows in 865ms, for 115606.94rows/sec
```

and

```
Loaded 1000000 rows in 9311ms, for 107399.85rows/sec
Loaded 1000000 rows in 10040ms, for 99601.59rows/sec
Loaded 1000000 rows in 9161ms, for 109158.39rows/sec
Loaded 1000000 rows in 7678ms, for 130242.25rows/sec
Loaded 1000000 rows in 9074ms, for 110204.98rows/sec
Loaded 1000000 rows in 8670ms, for 115340.25rows/sec
Loaded 1000000 rows in 8873ms, for 112701.45rows/sec
Loaded 1000000 rows in 8094ms, for 123548.31rows/sec
Loaded 1000000 rows in 10353ms, for 96590.36rows/sec
Loaded 1000000 rows in 8727ms, for 114586.91rows/sec
```

EF Core 5.02, SQL Server 2019 and EF running on desktop, Intel Core i9-09900K